# Solr: Using custom functions in the Data Import Handler

Tags: plugins, solr, dataimporthandler

I have successfully written a custom function and hooked it into my Solr engine.  However, I am having problems passing parameters into that function from within the data-import.xml import definition file.

I have tried to methods, one which passes in a field from the current entity query, and the other approach which tries to use a variable from the last query...no seem to work.

Attempt 1:  Pass in columns from current query:

```
<entity name="doc" query="SELECT id, date, ${dataimporter.functions.myfunc(id,date)} AS custom_value FROM Documents" />
```

This doesn't work as id and date seem to be passed in as literals, not the column values.

Attempt 2:

```
<entity name="doc" query="SELECT id, date FROM Documents">
  <entity name="special" query="SELECT ${dataimporter.functions.myfunc(${doc.id}, ${doc.date})} AS custom_value" >
          <field name="custom_value" column="custom_value" />
  </entity>
</entity>
```

This doesn't work because it gets confused from the variable within the variable.

Any suggestions on how to make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

`<entity name="doc" query="SELECT id, date, ${dataimporter.functions.myfunc(doc.id,doc.date)} AS custom_value FROM Documents" />`

Comment: Wow, that was easy, thanks!  I'm surprised on how very little documentation there is on this subject.  If anyone has pointers to some good documentation, please post here!  Or maybe the Solr book would have all this covered in detail?

Answer (score 1):

An other way to generate custom_value is using transformer tag

in transformer_row you can add more column to the row or write custom function to transform if you want.